# Different Nvidia cards

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I have a desktop with a Nvidia GeForce 210 1GB. I am going to buy an Nvidia GeForce GT 630 2GB. Is there a chance to run both of these video cards at he same time?  I think none of these cards support SLI but I do think of it both of them have PhysX.

Answer (score 2):

To run both cards in tandem, they both have to support SLI. Neither the [GT 630](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-630/specifications) nor the [210](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-210/specifications) support SLI.

[PhysX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhysX) is a physics rendering engine for nVidia video cards. It has nothing to do with SLI.

However, if you want to use multiple monitors, yes, you can have multiple video cards to add more monitors.

Comment: AFAIK only the very same GPUs can work together in SLi or Crossfire. As in you would need two GT630s instead of two different cards.